# string get replaced at the beginning instead of appended at the end in perl

Tags: perl

My intend is to add the file name to the end of folder path string. For example, adding `checkfile.tgz` at the end of `/u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4`. However, when I run the code as below

```
my $folderpath = "/u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4";
my $filepath = $folderpath . "/checkfile.tgz";
```

Instead of giving me

```
/u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/checkfile.tgz
```

it shows

```
/checkfile.tgzlder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
```

The string length does not change, while the first few characters get replaced by the string that need to append. So how should I solve this issue?

Comment: Please don't lie. The code that produced the output you specified is different than the code you provided. In the code you actually ran, `$folderpath` had a trailing Carriage Return

Comment: Hi. I've just added four spaces at the start of your lines of code. That means that StackOverflow will format those lines as code (as you can see). You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing it yourself in the future.

Comment: This is my first time to process the windows batch command returned file in perl script. And apparently I missed the \r at the end of the line. Big mistake. Thank you all for the helping.

Answer (score 3):

Running your code gave me exactly the output I expected.

Here's the program I ran:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $folderpath = "/u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4";
my $filepath = $folderpath . "/checkfile.tgz";

say "Folder path is: $folderpath";
say "File path is: $filepath";
```

And here's the output I got:

```
Folder path is: /u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
File path is: /u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/checkfile.tgz
```

If that's not what you saw, then please update your question to give a small but complete program that we can run which demonstrates your problem. You should also state exactly what out you expect to see.

As [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) says in a comment, it's almost certainly a problem with newlines and carriage returns - possibly compounded by transferring your file between Windows and Linux without making the appropriate line-end conversions.

**Update:** To back up ikemami's theory, here's a lightly-edited version of my test program (I've added a carriage return character to the end of `$folderpath`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $folderpath = "/u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4\r";
my $filepath = $folderpath . "/checkfile.tgz";

say "Folder path is: $folderpath";
say "File path is: $filepath";
```

And here's the output this program produces:

```
Folder path is: /u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
/checkfile.tgz/u/username/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4
```